# Which Proper Scoring rule for when?

Tags: logistic, accuracy, scoring-rules, credit-scoring

**Hi**, I'm quite new to statistics and have been tasked to evaluate if there is a difference in accuracy between 2 subpopulations in a logistic model.

The credit scoring company's model calculates the risk credit score (0-1 or 0-100%) of an individual defaulting and then they send this score to the banks who decide if they want to hand out a loan or not. Then a year later we get back info if the individual that had a loan approved have recieved a payment remark (binary 1 or 0). (We have no way of seeing for what risk scores they decide to give out loans)

Since we have one **continous dependent variable** and a **binary outcome variable** I've found calculating the acutal accuracy impossible and are now turning to Proper scoring rules to determine which model have the most "loss" in prediction compared to outcome.

I've found **Brier score** quite interesting for my occasion but there are so many scoring rules and few places document **when it's best to use which scoring rule**.

Would love an explanation, suggestion of alterative approach or link me to a place where this is discussed.

*Thank you for your time and consideration.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logarithmic loss vs Brier score vs AUC score](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/470380/logarithmic-loss-vs-brier-score-vs-auc-score) The trick is to recognize that the choice of probability cutoff (after modeling) depends on relative costs of false-positive and false-negative class assignments. If you start with an estimate of those relative costs, you can in principle choose a scoring rule that emphasizes probabilities near the corresponding cutoff.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Sadly I can not choose a cut of point given that the credit score is supplied to thousands of different banks. One bank might give out a loan to risk scores below 2%. Another 10%. Meaning no matter where I decide for my model to create a cut off point, it will not reflect reality since the banks all have a unique cut off point...

Comment: Hence why I got interested in brier score since it does not require a cut off point / Threshold. But to my knowledge, other scoring rules does not require a cut off point as well. Thus I have a hard time deciding on which one to use for which occasion.

Comment: As the linked duplicate thread indicates, the differences have to do with how much weight you put on different parts of the probability scale. As the answer from [Dikran Marsupial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/538582/28500) there says, log loss puts a lot of weight on errors near the extremes. The Brier score doesn't, and has the advantage of being easy to explain as the binary equivalent of mean-square error.

Comment: I'm more concerned about whether your assigned task is feasible regardless of your scoring choice. Say you had a perfectly calibrated default-prediction model. Then a bank that only gave out loans to those with less than a 1% default risk would seem necessarily have a better score (of any type) than a bank that gave out loans to those up to a 50% default risk. I'd recommend that you ask a new question focusing on the "subpopulations" you've been asked to compare, with enough detail to help evaluate whether such a comparison makes any sense without information about probability cutoffs by bank.